# Error persisting to mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble persisting data into mysql using hibernate. I'm using spring mvc and learning enterprise applications but having bit of trouble persisting into the database. I am creating two entities called Persons, and organization into mysql db. The schema called Lab2 for practice. Also using maven to build my project. I created the `webapp` folder under `myProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. I will like to know if I'm correctly configuring the hibernate.cfg.xml. I also created `hibernate.cfg.xml`under `WEB-INF` folder and below is my code:
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
                <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Lab2</property>
                <property name="connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
                <property name="connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="connection.password">root</property>
                <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
                <!--dialect-->
                <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
                <!--will print out sql queries to our console-->
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <!--names annotated entity class-->
                <mapping class="edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.models.Person"></mapping>
                <mapping class="edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.models.Organization"></mapping>

        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

From doing research and looking online what is `WEB-INF` I had to create the folder as it stores web.xml and loads all my compiled classes and executable files in the folder. 
Also included in `WEB-INF`is my web.xml. The web.xml loads all configurations. I pass the hibernate.cfg.xml file into web.xml as well as the services.xml(business logic files), as well as applicationContext.xml that does nothing for now.
Below is my web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Lab 2</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/services.xml, /WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is the dispatcher-servlet.xml file. This file listens to incoming request as well as sends out responses. It sends the request to controller. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.controller"  />


       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />
</beans>
```

My service.xml file loads up my service implementation for the PesronDao and OrganizationDao. Also I decided to add my database configurations in here as well since I will be using `SessionFactory interface`. I feel like this where my error happens as I cannot persist into mysql. Also when I define the `@Table` in my Person.java I get an error saying it `cannot resolve table person`. 
Below is service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


       <bean name="personService" class="edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.service.PersonImpl" autowire="byName"/>

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
              <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Lab2" />
              <property name="username" value="root" />
              <property name="password" value="root" />
       </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.models.Person</value>
                <value>edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.models.Organization</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> -->
      <context:component-scan base-package="edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.service" />
</beans>
```

Below is applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
</beans>
```

Below is my error:

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
03-Nov-2015 18:30:25.837 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute could not read a hi value
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'lab2.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.service.PersonImpl.createPerson(PersonImpl.java:48)
    at edu.sjsu.cmpe275.lab2.controller.Controllers.home(Controllers.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please could someone assist me and I think the error comes from the way I configured my hibernate.cfg.xml file as well as the services.xml file as I feel this where the error is happening. Please could some assist me in spotting the error or correct me in what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that table `lab2.hibernate_sequence` doesn't exist. This table is used by Hibernate to hold pid sequence. This table is created by Hibernate when you do something like this in configuration

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Your configuration looks very strange one. You have database connection properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml` and in `service.xml`. Those properties are differ from each other. So I think Hibernate doesn't create any table in database on startup.